# Find the general solution of $x^3y^{\prime \prime \prime} + y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to use the Frobenius technique, but I am unable to find the solution by infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

From the format the more general ODE $x^ny^{(n)}+y=0$ it is clear that there are numbers $r$ such that $y=x^r$ is a solution.

$$y^{(n)}=r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)x^{r-n}$$

Thus the values of $r$ that work obey $r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)+1=0$. This is an equation of degree $n$. It only needs to be checked that the $n$ roots are all simple (not always the case, e.g. $n=4$) since it is pretty straight forward to use the Wronskian to show that the $n$ power functions we get are the basis of the general solution for $\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ functions. If any pair of roots are $r_{\pm}=a\pm bi\notin\mathbb{R}$ and we want to solve for $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ functions then observe $x^{r_\pm}=x^a\cos(b\ln x)\pm ix^a\sin(b\ln x)$ so that instead of the two basis elements $x^{r_\pm}$ you will use $x^a\cos(b\ln x)$ and $x^a\sin(b\ln x)$.

Therefore if $r_1,\cdots,r_n$ are the solutions to the polynomial equation then the general solution to the ODE is $y=\sum_{k=1}^nC_kx^{r_k}$.

$n=1$: $y=C_1\frac{1}{x}$

$n=2$: $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(C_1\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln x\right)+C_2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln x\right)\right)$

$n=3$: $y=C_1x^{-r}+C_2x^{r/2}(C_2\cos(b\ln x)+C_3\sin (b\ln x))$ where

$$r=\frac{\sqrt[3]{108+12\sqrt{69}}+\sqrt[3]{108-12\sqrt{69}}}{6}$$
$$b=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{108+12\sqrt{69}}-\sqrt[3]{108-12\sqrt{69}}\right)\sqrt{3}}{12}$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_k:=x^k[y]$ then $x^k[x^3y^{(3)}+y]=a_kp(k),\,p(k):=k^3-3k^2+2k+1$. Each of the [three roots of $p$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+k%5E3-3k%5E2%2B2k%2B1%3D0) provides a linearly independent solution $y=x^k$. These span the $3$-dimensional vector space of solutions.

Comment: But, two roots are complex.

Comment: @Mathsource That's OK. If $u,\,v\in\Bbb R$ then $x^{u+iv}=x^u\exp(iv\ln x)$. Since the non-real roots are of the form $u\pm iv$, we can use $x^u\cos(v\ln x),\,x^u\sin(v\ln x)$ as a real-to-real basis of the $2$-dimensional space using the non-real roots. I'll leave what happens for $x<0$ as an exercise, using $\ln x=\ln|x|+i\pi(2n+1),\,n\in\Bbb Z$.